# How to integrate new data to T SNE?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, dimensionality-reduction

I need to integrate a new data without rexcute the tSNE algorithme for the all data.

Is there a possibility to do this because the pickle does not work well.

```
tsne = TSNE(n_components=2, verbose=1, perplexity=30, n_iter=1000, learning_rate=30, early_exaggeration=12)
tsne_results = tsne.fit_transform(allData)
pickle.dump(tsne, open("TSNE.SAVED", 'wb'))
```

It seems to me that I do not have such a possibility, but I hope there is a way to solve this problem

Comment: I think that is hard (impossible?) in t-SNE; you might want to check out UMAP, where this can be done as far as I know.

Comment: yep, but unfortunately I can't install new libraries :(

Comment: Look at the last point of [the t-SNE FAQ](http://lvdmaaten.github.io/tsne/#faq) : It's not possible directly, but there's a paper that describes one possible approach.